# How phpunit test, if some javascript file exist in 1. header 2. body?

Tags: phpunit

How phpunit test, if some javascript file exist in 1. header 2. body?

Example (How phpunit test existent of file1.js in head + file2.js in body?):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Yosef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you can test it as

```
$this->assertTrue($this->isElementPresent("//head/script[@src='file1.js']"));
$this->assertTrue($this->isElementPresent("//body/script[@src='file2.js']"));
```

Comment: Here $this is object of phpunit on which test case has been called.